# How can i access the Firebase Service Account stored in an Environment Variable

Tags: firebase, express, server, jwt

I have firebase service account in my .env file . The main problem is I am unable to access those in index.js file. I have already tried similar questions in stackoverflow . But those were not helpful to me.

Here is my index.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const { ObjectId } = require("mongodb");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
require("dotenv").config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
//firebase admin initialization
const serviceAccount = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT);
admin.initializeApp({
credential : admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
}),
});

//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
```

The occurred error :

[error image](https://i.ibb.co/R4fq9GK/Whats-App-Image-2022-01-05-at-11-33-54-PM.jpg)

.env file:

[env file](https://i.ibb.co/3k3qTXn/Whats-App-Image-2022-01-05-at-11-33-54-PM-1.jpg)

Comment: You should paste the code instead of link. Links can go stale, but if you paste the code it will last. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also gone through the same problem. I think this isn't the correct way to retrieve the environment variables.

You can try to retrieve it like this-

```
//firebase admin initialization
const serviceAccount = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT);
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: serviceAccount.project_id,
    clientEmail: serviceAccount.client_email,
    privateKey: serviceAccount.private_key.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
  }),
});
```

Hope it'll work.